# ruby on rails yield to new ruby layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, yield

In a page I'm working on , i have overridden the `application.html.erb` because the layout is complex for pages like signup / login and some others.

So i created a new layout and I'm rendering it through the controller's action.

```
def new
  render :layout => '../path/newlayout.html.erb'
  ...
end
```

Question is , can i use another layout as a "secondary" `application.html.erb`?

Can i `<%yield%>` to the `newlayout.html.erb` ?

Answer (score 0):

As i searched further , i stumbled upon **partials**!

just create a file with the naming convention `"_login.html.erb"` in the same folder as your `newlayout.html.erb`

and just use `<%= render 'login' %>`

in the same position and way that you'd use `<%yield%>`